# PDFBox will not Inflate some PDF files

Tags: java, apache, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using pdfbox 1.8.8 to convert pdf files to graphic images.

`BufferedImage bufferedImage = pdPage.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, resolution);`

But while converting I sometimes get this exception:

java.io.IOException which originally was a DataFormatException thrown by
org.apache.pdfbox.filter.FlateFilter.decode(FlateFilter.java:109)

I cannot see anything special regarding to the PDF File I want to convert. The pdf analyser told me that the PDF file has been compressed with FlateDecode. I can see the pdf file with the adobe reader, so what is wrong with this file? How can I pdfbox make the convert this file?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Current version is 1.8.9. Anyway, either the file is really corrupt (Adobe Reader often silently fails), or the file is encrypted (but then you should have seen a warning). The best would be that you upload the file somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is right, that it is not the current version, but the DataFormatException will be thrown by java.util.zip.Inflater. The pdf files are not encrypted.

Comment: The java.util.zip.Inflater has the job of decompressing Flate encoded streams, so it will "throw" if such a stream is corrupt. I'd need the file to tell more, i.e. whether the stream is really corrupt or whether there is has another cause.

Comment: In the 1.8 versions, sometimes it will work if the file is opened with .loadNonSeq() instead of load(). Alternatively, try the 2.0 version.